# how to disable metrics calculation in styleGAN2?

Tags: deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network, stylegan

Metrics calculation is very time consuming in stylegan2 is there any way to disable this feature.
I want to train my network on Colab an this takes a lot of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `--metrics=None` to your `!python train.py` command line